# Login Redirection Issue

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect

When I log into my web application, it doesn’t redirect to the custom redirect page created instead it redirects to the default accounts/profile url in Django. Below are my codes:

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='myapp/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('phase1/', views.phase1_view, name='phase1'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.conf import settings
#Phases Details View
@login_required
def phase1_view(request):
    settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/myapp/phase1/'
    return render(request, 'myapp/phase1.html')

#Logout View

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')

#Login View
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('phase1') 
        else:
            return render(request, 'myapp/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login credentials'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'myapp/login.html')
```

settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

login.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div>
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="text-input" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="text-input" required>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" class="primary-btn">Sign In</button>

                </form>
```

I tried to add LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/myapp/phase1/' in settings.py but it not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your login url setting is wrong, it shall be

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',views.login),
    path('logout/',views.logout),
]
```

You are calling the provided ones, not your implemented views.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the settings.py modifications you're making are getting overidden by django's default ones, try this:

1 - Remove the **settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL** line from your phase1_view function in views.py. You don't need to set this in your view function.

2 - Update urls.py to include a LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL setting in the Django authentication views. Here's an updated urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='myapp/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('phase1/', views.phase1_view, name='phase1'),
]

# new lines
from django.conf import settings
settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/myapp/phase1/'
```

Comment: Please do not advice to update Django settings externally, it's almost always a bad idea (and clearly bad in this case). One should modify `settings.py` of main project instead (`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` envvar points to that file), defining `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ...` there

Comment: i 100% agree with you, only thing made me propose this solution is him saying "I tried to add LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/myapp/phase1/' in settings.py but it not worked.", so i provided this as quick fix.